# How can I remove the NA label in my GGplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**my original code**
`my_graph10 <- ggplot(Adata, aes(x = SVL, y = Fi)) + geom_point(aes(color = Morph)) + labs(x = "SVL (mm)", y = "Front Inner Limb (mm)") + geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,aes(color = Morph,linetype = Morph)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "steelblue"))` results in this
[Legend NA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRzrh.jpg)

after reading online, many said to use na.translate = F ; therefore I added this to the code
`my_graph11 <- ggplot(Adata, aes(x = SVL, y = Fo)) + geom_point(aes(color = Morph)) + labs(x = "SVL (mm)", y = "Front Outer Limb (mm)") + geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,aes(color = Morph,linetype = Morph)) + scale_color_manual(**na.translate = F**, values = c("orange", "steelblue")`  and I am left with this
[Two Legends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoUR1.jpg)

However, when I do so, it removes the NA from the original legend, but adds a new legend for linetype, under which NA is still listed. I attempted to do the same code for linetype but receive this error message "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 0 provided"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `remove_missing`

```r
# Let's create some sample data first
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2020)
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 100)
df <- data.frame(
    x = x, 
    y = rnorm(length(x)), 
    Morph = sample(c("S", "U", NA), length(x), replace = TRUE))

# Use `remove_missing` with `na.rm = TRUE` to remove NA rows
ggplot(remove_missing(df, na.rm = TRUE), aes(x, y, colour = Morph)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(aes(linetype = Morph), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or alternatively you use `na.omit`

```r
ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x, y, colour = Morph)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(aes(linetype = Morph), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any difference in behavior with `na.omit/remove_missing` other than the `na.rm`

Comment: This did not work. NA is still in the legend.

Comment: @Kelsey I assume this has to do with your "NA"s not really being `NA`s. Note that `"NA"` != `NA`. This is a good example for why it is important to include sample data in a reproducible format (e.g. using `dput`).